# Treat one object in Makefile separately

Tags: c, makefile

I have a Makefile which is used to build several different programs.  These programs use common object files.

One program crashes with `*** buffer overflow detected ***` when one of the modules that is linked to it is compiled with any optimizations.

Here is the Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
WFLAGS=-W \
   -Wall \
   -Werror \
   -Wextra \
   -Wshadow \
   -Wcast-qual \
   -Wcast-align \
   -Wwrite-strings \
   -Wpointer-arith \
   -Wnested-externs \
   -Wstrict-prototypes \
   -Wmissing-prototypes
CFLAGS=$(WFLAGS) \
   -g \
   -O2 \
   -ansi \
   -pedantic \
   -Dinline= \
   -fno-common \
   -fshort-enums
LFLAGS=-lm
TARGETS=lzdata \
    lzmcro \
    mknlrescs \
    mknrescs \
    levels \
    degen
OBJ1=couplings.o \
 crossing.o \
 element.o \
 lzdata.o \
 utils.o \
 lzcxs.o \
 nist.o
OBJ2=lzmcro.o
OBJ3=mknlrescs.o \
 csheader.o \
 xsection.o \
 labels.o \
 csdata.o \
 utils.o
OBJ4=mknrescs.o \
 csheader.o \
 xsection.o \
 labels.o \
 csdata.o \
 utils.o
OBJ5=levels.o \
 utils.o
OBJ6=degen.o \
 utils.o \
 nist.o
OBJECTS=$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2) $(OBJ3) $(OBJ4) $(OBJ5) $(OBJ6)
SOURCES=mknlrescs.c \
    couplings.c \
    mknrescs.c \
    xsection.c \
    crossing.c \
    csheader.c \
    element.c \
    csdata.c \
    labels.c \
    lzmcro.c \
    lzdata.c \
    levels.c \
    degen.c \
    utils.c \
    lzcxs.c \
    nist.c
HEADERS=couplings.h \
    xsection.h \
    csheader.h \
    crossing.h \
    element.h \
    csdata.h \
    labels.h \
    utils.h \
    lzcxs.h \
    nist.h
MANPAGES=lzdata.1\
     lzmcro.1
SCRIPTS=mclz.sh \
    fnist1.pl \
    fnist2.pl
DATAFILES=elements.dat
ALL=$(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) $(MANPAGES) $(SCRIPTS) $(DATAFILES)

all: $(TARGETS)

levels: $(OBJ5)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^

degen: $(OBJ6)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^

mknlrescs: $(OBJ3)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^ 

mknrescs: $(OBJ4)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^

lzmcro: $(OBJ2)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LFLAGS)

lzdata: $(OBJ1)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)

%.o: %.c %.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

install: $(TARGETS)
mv $^ /usr/local/bin

clean:
@rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGETS)
```

The program that crashes is `mknrescs` when `labels.c` is compiled with optimizations.

I could remove `-O2` from the `CFLAGS` macro, but I would rather not, since some programs take a while and that will make them even slower.

I could build each object separately, instead of using this rule: `%.o: %.c %.h`.

The other programs, which used `labels.o` do not crash, even if it is compiled with optimzations.

So, what other options to I have to build ONLY `labels.o` with no optimizations ONLY when it is linked to `mknrescs`?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you should fix that crash problem instead of try to work around it.

Comment: I tried for several hours.  In the process of trying to fix it, that's when I discovered it would work if I compiled it with no optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a target-specific variable for `labels.o` to override the `CFLAGS` setting:

```
labels.o: CFLAGS = $(WFLAGS) -g -O0 -ansi -pedantic -Dinline= -fno-common -fshort-enums
```

This variable will apply to all rules building `labels.o`, so it will be built with no optimization.  Since all the program targets share the same object file, however, they'll all use the non-optimized version.  You can simplify this a bit by splitting the optimization level out of the `CFLAGS` var:

```
OPTLEVEL=2
CFLAGS=$(WFLAGS) \
-g \
-O$(OPTLEVEL) \
-ansi \
-pedantic \
-Dinline= \
-fno-common \
-fshort-enums

labels.o: OPTLEVEL = 0
```

If you really *must* have the non-optimized version just for the one program and not for the others, you need to use a different name for the object file.  You can add a generic rule to generate unoptimized objects:

```
%-noopt.o: %.c %.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS_NOOPT) -c -o $@ $<
```

define the `CFLAGS_NOOPT` variable the same as `CFLAGS` but with `-O0`, and then change your `OBJ` list for the problematic binary to include `labels-noopt.o` instead of `labels.o`